# How can I highlight java code via CSS?

Tags: java, css, highlight

I saw some cool code highlighting that looked like code in Eclipse, however I can't find it.  :(  Do you know any cool java code highlight css?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you want [code-prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/)

Supports a bunch of different languages (including Java).  Here are the [docs/examples](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html).

Comment: Now docs/examples link has moved to [here](https://github.com/google/code-prettify)

Answer (score 7):

You might want to look at [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter)

Answer (score 1):

I've used [GeSHi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/) once, and it was OK, but it's not that I've tried any other and compared them.

Answer (score 1):

I use [code2html](http://www.palfrader.org/code2html/) for my own website. However, as the "official" version does not support CSS, I use my own version, instead. This patched CSS-enabled version can be downloaded [on my website](http://www.field-theory.org/software/index.html#code2html).