# Rich Text Display Component for Java

Tags: java

Is there any library which provide a text panel with basic formatting features.
Such as line numbering, Keyword coloring and others.

I want to display a code inside my application window. I already try to use JTextPane. But it is easy if there exist are any UI Components that meets my requirements.

note : I want to display the code same as when it is open using notepad++ or any code editor.

Comment: Some similar discussions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596958/how-can-i-highlight-java-code-via-css and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221570/what-code-highlighting-libs-are-there-for-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864688/where-can-i-find-a-syntax-highlighting-library-for-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used [jsyntaxpane](http://code.google.com/p/jsyntaxpane/) with some success.